# "Unable to contact test backend running in app" when trying to run Xamarin UITest locally

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.uitest

I am in the early process of learning how to automate Xamarin apps for my company.  I started out by just cloning the [TailWind Traders](https://github.com/Microsoft/TailwindTraders-Mobile) app from Microsoft to make sure my system is configured correctly, but I'm running into an issue. After modifying `AppManager.cs` to use the .app file and attempting to run a single iOS test, I see the app load in the simulator, I get a Mac alert saying "Do you want the application 'DeviceAgent-Runner.app' to accept incoming network transmissions", and then the test fails with this message:

```
System.Exception : Unable to contact test backend running in app. Check that your app is running and that it is properly configured:

For Xamain.iOS applications,  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/preparing-for-upload/xamarin-ios-uitest

For native iOS applications,  https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Tutorial%3A-How-to-add-Calabash-to-Xcode
```

Going to that website, I see that it is helping the user configure running tests AppCenter, but I don't want to do that. I simply want to run a test locally on my machine.  In trying to fix this, I've uninstalled the Xamarin Test Cloud Agent package and deleted the `#if ENABLE_TEST_CLOUD` block from `AppDelegate.cs`.  But, it's still happening. How do I run an iOS test locally?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automate uitest using xamarin, it is necessary to add test cloud agent nuget in your xamarin ios project which enable linking to Calabash & install the device agent runner in your mobile. For more detail visit on Microsoft site.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/uitest/preparing-for-upload-ios

Whether you upload your test on app enter or run it locally. You have to add test cloud agent nuget in xamarin ios. If you are using native iOS, Calabash linking require to run xamarin uitest.